# Xamarin.Forms AbsoluteLayout child with an absolute height and proportional width

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I'm using [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout) to render my view, essentially I have a map filled view and a button aligned to the bottom of the AbsoluteLayout

```
AbsoluteLayout (fill)
|--View (fill)
|--Button (bottom, full-width, 200 height)
```

Here is my code which uses [proportional values](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/#Proportional_Values) to define the layout:

```
<AbsoluteLayout 
     VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <maps:Map 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" /> 
             <Button
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,0.5,0.15"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
             // ... other controls ... //
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

It works perfectly fine except the fact that my button has a dynamic height (proportional to the parent height). I want to keep is static as long as I have other styles which makes it ugly whenever height is dynamic (e.g. `BorderRadius`).

I tried to use [absolute values](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/#AbsoluteLayoutFlags) for the button but now I'm constrained to have both height and width defined in absolute values while I want only the height to be defined in absolute values and width continue to take whole parent width span.

Comment: Is the goal to have both position and width be proportional, and height (only) be absolute?  If so, you can specify a comma-separated list on the button: AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,WidthProportional".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In AbsoluteLayout we can determine which four properties to be proportional or absolute(static) by setting AbsoluteLayout's LayoutFlagsAs. So as @DavidS mentioned, you can set Button's height as static this way (say 50):

```
<AbsoluteLayout 
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <maps:Map 
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" /> 
             <Button
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,1,0.5,50"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional,WidthPropor‌​tional" />
             // ... other controls ... //
</AbsoluteLayout>
```